# Allow for categorizing favorites

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I have a suggestion regarding marking a question as favorite. Stack Overflow provides this feature and I can go in my profile and see list of favorites.

But, over time, this list gets too long and difficult to search in. I suggest that SO allow users to categorize their own favorites (like using tags), so its easier to manage them, and easier to find the right question among favorites quickly.

Comment: Yeah. Right now favorites are useless. We can't even search thru them.

Comment: It would also be great to be able to search not only favorites, but also your own answers and questions (or at least organize them by tags)

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes. But I took a while to discover it (I hadn't yet when I wrote this comment).

Answer (score 6):

I’d be against adding a new method of categorization just for favorites—if you care enough, just use your browser’s bookmarking facility and organize it with whatever means your browser provides.

That said, searching would be useful…but note that we already have this feature! Just use the normal search facility and add `infavorites:mine`. This is documented in the [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). It might be useful to add a little search box that does this for you, though; as is, you have to dig through the help to figure out that this feature exists.

Similar remarks apply to [helderdarocha's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251412/marking-a-question-as-favorite#comment2981_251412); just use `user:me` rather than `infavorites:mine`.

Answer (score 1):

like answer of [@icktoofay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/200291/icktoofay) you can search into your favorites question by Tag using [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) Just type tag name into `[]` then `infavorites:mine`

**Example:**

I want to search into my favorites question with tag php, Just write into search box :

```
[php] infavorites:mine
```